# git merging the files from the branch to master

Tags: linux, git

1) I have created a branch

```
$ mkdir newV4
$ git checkout -b newV4
Switched to a new branch 'newV4'
$ cd newV4/
```

2) creating a sample file and pushing it to the repo

```
$touch new.log
$ git add new.log 
$ git status
On branch newV4
Changes to be committed:
(use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   new.log

$ git commit -m "newchange"
[newV4 d1d982d] newchange
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
create mode 100644 newV4/new.log
$ git push --all
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 300 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (1/1), completed with 1 local object.
To https://github.com/chay24/devops.git
   98a973e..bfa3aa5  master -> master
* [new branch]      newV4 -> newV4
```

3) Merging with the manger ----- I am not getting the new.log to my master branch

```
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
$ ls
2.log  3.log  4.log  5.log  new  newV  newV2  newV3  test.log
$ git merge newV4
Updating bfa3aa5..d1d982d
Fast-forward
 newV4/new.log | 0
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 newV4/new.log
$ ls
2.log  3.log  4.log  5.log  new  newV  newV2  newV3  newV4  test.log
```

I want to get the new file into my master branch, how can I do that?

Comment: you created the file on the `newV4` folder and that folder is listed in your  output's last line.

Comment: yeah but can I the file in newV4 in the master directory?

Comment: Have you checked inside the `newV4` folder?

Answer (score 0):

your process seems a little incorrect.. here's what I do:

```
$ git checkout -b hotfix/my-branch -t origin/master
$ mkdir test_folder
$ touch test_folder/test.php
$ git add test_folder
$ git commit -m "adding test"
$ git push -u origin HEAD
```

this will checkout the working tree to a new branch called `hotfix/my-branch` with an `upstream` set to `origin/master`. After doing your work you use

```
$ git push -u origin HEAD
```

this pushes the current `HEAD` to your remote origin, making it available globally (globally as in, to those who have access).

when you want to merge, come back to your local and do

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge hotfix/my-branch
$ git push -u origin master
```

this will merge `hotfix/my-branch` into `origin/master` once pushed.

Comment: Waht is hotfix/my-branch in the first line

Comment: @user2159389 my example branch - otherwise you'll just copy and paste instead of learn :)

Comment: @user2159389 does it come back with any errors? where is your origin hosted? :)

Comment: @user2159389 your output shows it working? if you do `git checkout master` and you can see the test_folder then it worked..